# Error Handling: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am having a problem with the user model that I'm using with Mongoose and MongoDB to create each profile in my database. It works fine to post one user, but throws the following error if I logout and try again:

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: CourtAPIDev.users index: trackers.case_id_1 dup key: { : null }",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: CourtAPIDev.users index: trackers.case_id_1 dup key: { : null }"
}
```

According to mongoose documentation: **If there is more than one document (a second user) without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.** I don't know how to set this _id property for the trackers property –– I thought it generated automatically!

Here's the trackers part of my Schema. And the relevant case_id property, which seems to be throwing the "null" error.

[image]
[image]

The whole repository can be found on my Github here, but the likely problem spots are the ones I highlighted, I think. Here's the github link: https://github.com/KingOfCramers/node_login_with_trackers

user model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 1,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (value) => {
                return validator.isEmail(value);
            },
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    tokens: [{
        access: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    trackers: {
        tweets: [TwitterSchema],
        legislation: [LegislationSchema],
        court_cases: [CourtCaseSchema]
    },
    frequency: [EmailSchema]
});
```

Express route:

```
app.post("/users", (req,res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    body.frequency = {
        alert_time: new Date(),
        email: req.body.email
    }
    var user = new User(body);

    user.save().then(() => {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header("x-auth", token);
        res.send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});
```

Test (mocha):

```
 it("Should post a new user", (done) => {
        var email = "uniqueemail@example.com"
        var password = "9webipasd"
        supertest(app)
            .post("/users") // Post request to the /todos URL
            .send({
                email,
                password
            })
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect(res.headers).toIncludeKey('x-auth')
                expect(res.body._id).toExist();
                expect(res.body.email).toBe(email);
            })
            .end((err) => {
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }
                User.findOne({email}).then((user) => {
                    expect(user).toExist();
                    expect(user.password).toNotBe(password);
                    done();
                }).catch((e) => done(e));
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was to do with my mongodb database, not any of my code. After searching around online, I found that if I logged into the mongo shell and then dropped all indexes from the users collection, it solved my problem. Could someone explain why this was causing my program to crash? I think it may have to do with an old user model, but I don't really understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is an index on CourtCaseSchema.case_id which does not allow duplicates.

I think you could check (in a mongo shell) that with `CourtAPIDev.court_cases.getIndexes()` (I think your db is named `CourtAPIDev` and the collection is named `court_cases` but I am not sure about that).

Also if you clean the test db after each run, that would explain why the tests are passing, since there is no more than one user.

Comment: My collection is named users, which has "trackers" in the Schema. That's where the error is happening.

Comment: I agree with you, however, since the UserSchema is linked to the CourtCaseSchema, which is throwing the error I believe this come from an index in CourtCaseSchema, since there is no unique: true.
Did you try to see the index for ALL your collections in a mongo shell ?

Comment: As far as I know, mongo will create one "table" for each of your schema, so looking only  the users may not give enough infos

Answer (score 0):

**Even if you have all of your keys as unique=False**, you may still get *E11000 duplicate key error*. So in that case, just follow these steps and check if your error is resolved.

- Delete all documents from the collection (e.g. db.collection_name.deleteMany({}))
- Drop the COLLECTION (**NOT THE DATABASE**) (e.g db.collection_name.drop())

*Cheers !!*